# Pell's Equation and its importance

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Currently I am studying [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation). Why do we need to assume $n$ is nonsquare integer? What if $\sqrt{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$ ? Also why is this type of equation so important?

Comment: If $n=a^2m$ where $m$ is non-square integer, we can write $x^2-m(ay)^2=1$

Comment: why must $n=a^2m$? Can it be $n=a^2$ only?

Comment: @Idnotknow, then we shall have $x^2-y^2=1\implies x=0?y=0?$

Comment: @bof: Pell's equation is taught in the my university number theory course. I'm not self studying it.

Comment: If $\sqrt{n}\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $n$ is a perfect square, say $n = m^2$. Then, $x^2 - n y^2 = x^2 - (m y)^2 = 1$, so we are looking for two numbers ($x$ and $my$) whose squares are 1 apart. The only solution is $x = 1$ and $my = 0$, so $y = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your final question, there are quite a number of applications of Pell's equation, such as (possibly in decreasing order of importance):

- Finding units in quadratic number fields (and proving results about them), as [explained here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation#Algebraic_number_theory).
- Solving some seemingly unrelated diophantine problems, such as finding numbers which are simultaneously square and triangle numbers (or more generally are simultaneously polygonal numbers of various types).
- Finding good rational approximations for $\sqrt{d}$. For example one of the solutions of $x^2-2y^2=1$ is $x = 577, y = 408$, and this gives the approximation $\sqrt{2} \simeq \frac{577}{408} = 1.4142156$.
- Convincing students that continued fractions are still worth studying these days.
- Proving the impossibility of solving a [peculiar diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/169017/32441).